# Get random Item from array node, when trying to set it gives a random index

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

From the docs
[RandomArrayItem](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/Array/RandomArrayItem/)

The act of setting the index of the random array item is also random which should not be according to the documentation
[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw9Vp.jpg)

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: Either a bug, or your breakpoint is in a weird place. Breaking 9n the set function itself should give you the right result.

Answer (score 0):

It should work according to documentation, the problem may occur if you check the value too early. Consider that the values are updated after over them in debug mode. As you can see here:

[image: checking value later]

Otherwise if check it too early you'll the default value of the variable which is in this case 0:

[image: checking value too early]